# Larger MS-DOS Img file?

Tags: operating-systems, ms-dos, disk-operating-system

I am making an operating system based on ms-dos and using a program called win image to edit an  ms-dos .img file, the program only lets me inject at total size of 2.88mb worth of files
and i would like to inject an unlimited amount of files into my ms-dos based OS img file.

Answer (score 0):

The 2.88 mb comes from a double density diskette. A normal diskette is 1.44 mb.

See if you can change the image type to something other than diskette, such as a Zipdrive disk (100 mb) or a Jazzdrive disk (1 gb).

Do note that msdos likely only can boot from either a harddisk image or a diskdrive image.

Comment: On a PC "double density" usually refers to diskettes up to 720k. 1.4Mb is high density and 2.8Mb is "extended" or "extra-high" density.